# EF Code First - WithMany()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I recently came by the class `ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<TEntity, TTarget>`
, and within that class there I found a method named `WithMany()` with 2 overloads.

The first overload:
`WithMany()`

> Configures the relationship to be
>   many:many without a navigation
>   property on the other side of the
>   relationship.

The second overload:
`WithMany(Expression<Func<TTarget, ICollection<TEntity>>>)`

> Configures the relationship to be
>   many:many with a navigation property
>   on the other side of the relationship.

Now is my question, why would you configure a relationship to be many:many without a navigation property (the first overload)? I dont see any scenarios where that would be helpful... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

An example might be this model:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**If you are never interested to retrieve all users which are in a specific role**, adding a navigation property ...

```
public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

... to the `Role` class would be unnecessary overhead.

But you still must EF tell that a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Role` exists ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
            .WithMany();
```

... because the default convention mappings would create a wrong relationship, namely a one-to-many relationship, corresponding to this mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
            .WithOptional();
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that the choice for a navigation property is *on the other side of the target*.

Let's look at an example, even though this specific case might not be the perfect illustrator of my point... If you want to keep track of math tests, and re-use questions, you might have two tables (`Tests` and `Questions`) which have a many-to-many relationship; each test has several questions, and each question can appear on several tests. However, you might not ever need to get a collection of tests that a specific question is on - even though you know that questions can appear on more than one test, you aren't interested in which.
Thus, you use the `.WithMany()` overload when declaring this, so you get a navigational property to get the questions of a test (`theTest.Questions()`) but no navigational property the other way (`theQuestion.Tests()`). But you still need a many-to-many relationship, since both tests and questions can have many of the other.
I agree that in this specific case this setup might not make sense, but there is certainly cases where it does, and in those cases the `.WithMany()` overload lets you get by without defining properties (and a lambda expression for each one of them) you'll never need.