# EF Code-First: Many-to-many with one direction navigation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a code-first model where a Person can have many favourite Movies, but I don't want a FK in the Movies table.

The only way to achieve this, is to get EF to create a link table between the two entities, and to do that (afaik) I have create a collection property on the Movies entity relating to Person...

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Movie> FavouriteMovies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Person> People { get; set; } // I don't want this here :(
}
```

I want Movie to look like this...

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But in doing that, the EF won't create a link table, it will just whack a Person_Id FK column in the Movies table.

I don't want this to happen, as Movies shouldn't have anything to do with People, and I might want to relate it to something else.

So how do I have my cake and eat it?

Comment: I think you want to look at this question / answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927272/ef-code-first-withmany

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136026/unidirectional-many-to-many-realtionship-with-code-first-entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

It should. How do you add your entities ? 
Here's a sample:

```
public class Character : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsEvil { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Videogame> Videogames { get; set; } 
}
public class Videogame : BaseEntity 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleasedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Here's where the record is added :

```
[Test]
public void CreateJoinTable()
{
    var character = new Character() {Name = "Wario", IsEvil = true};
    var videogame = new Videogame() {Name = "Super Mario Bros 20", ReleasedDate = DateTime.Now , Characters = new Collection<Character>()};
    videogame.Characters.Add(character);
    var context = new NerdContext();
    context.Add(videogame);
    context.SaveAllChanges();
}
```

Here's where the snippet come from : http://george2giga.com/2012/05/02/easy-join-tables-with-ef-code-first/

Comment: I add them the same way you showed in the example, but the problem I have is that Character should have no properties in there relating to Videogame. So if we take out the Videogames property from Character, EF won't create that link table.  How do I get it to to create the link table in this instance?

Comment: The character will only have a navigation property that links to videogames. Logically this is correct because the tables are linked within the join table and a many to many relationship is established. You could define an interface for the Character that doesn't have the list, or define your mapping rules using the ef fluent configuration. Personally I don't think it worth to overcomplicate such a simple implementation. Better to define an interface or map your POCO to a new class with the field you need.