# can you have many to many and one to many without Collection properties on the other end in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

this is my current working solution:

```
public class Person
{
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public Foo BonusFoo { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{        
    public ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Persons2 { get; set; }
}

public class MemContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(b => b.Foos)
            .WithMany(o => o.Persons);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(o => o.BonusFoo)
            .WithMany(o => o.Persons2);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I will **never** actually need to access in code `Foo.Persons` or `Foo.Persons2`, is it possible to have the same configuration but without these 2 properties on the `Foo` ?

Comment: Yes, just use `.WithMany()` not nominating any reverse navigation property. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927272/ef-code-first-withmany

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Code First - WithMany()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927272/ef-code-first-withmany)

Comment: @StevePy that doesn't build "No overload for method 'WithMany' takes 0 arguments".
I'm using .net 6

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't notice there was a one-to-many and many-to-many.  One to many the WithMany reverse navigation is optional, ManyToMany the reverse is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 7.0+):**

EF Core 7 added support for [Unidirectional many-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#unidirectional-many-to-many-relationships), so since then the answer for all type of relationships is positive.

**Original:**

The answer for one-to-many is positive (yes). Remove `Persons2` property from `Foo` and use `WithMany` w/o passing navigation property (since there isn't):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(o => o.BonusFoo)
    .WithMany(); // <--
```

The answer for many-to-many is negative(no) currently (EF Core 5, 6) as explained at the beginning of the [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) documentation:

> Many-to-many relationships **require** a collection navigation property **on both sides**.

It will be possible though in the upcoming EF Core 7 - [Support unidirectional many-to-many relationships through shadow navigations #3864](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3864).

Until then, keep the `Person.Foos` and `Foo.Persons` collection properties in the model (even if you "don't need" the later) and the existing fluent configuration.